# Overclock AMD Sapphire RX 580 GPU on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, radeon, overclocking, amdgpu-pro

I have Sapphire RX 580 nitro+ GPU and want to overclock it on Ubuntu 16.04. I thought I would easily do this using `amdconfig` but it is [no longer supported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD?action=show&redirect=BinaryDriverHowto%2FATI) so I installed [Radeon™ Software for Linux® Driver Version 17.50 for Ubuntu 16.04.3](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx) However, on this new driver I can't find similar functionality to `amdconfig`.

I found [PolarisBiosEditor](https://github.com/jaschaknack/PolarisBiosEditor), [radeon profile](https://github.com/marazmista/radeon-profile) (This one I wasn't able to install, because *qmake: could not exec*)

**Is there proprietary overclocking functionality included within AMDGPU-PRO drivers that I installed? If not what other tools should I use?**

Comment: maybe give this a shot? https://community.amd.com/thread/201392